# Shipping library in the jar file

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

When I add a library to my project bin directory and it is shipped in the jar file.

Is it now statically linked or dynamically linked with the code?

Thanks

Comment: you better not add library to bin folder

Comment: Are you talking about a JAR-library or a native/JNI-library?

Comment: yes I'm using eclipse
and its an external JAR-library

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a DLL / shared object / native binary here? There is no such thing as static or dynamic linking in Java world. There are only jars which you put on the classpath. Any natives should be in the OS specific native search path. There is no standard for a 'bin' directory, but an IDE might facilitate something like that. You'd have to check the manual of the IDE you're using.

I tend to put any natives used in the directory where the java command is invoked. Since I always build executable jars, the natives go in the same directory as the jar. Nice and stupid, no configuration needed.